# Upload an image from a client-side webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

One of the modules in our project is to upload an image from a webpage to mongo database using nodejs. We have completed connecting to a mongo database and upload an image using physical location of the image on the system, but we are not able to make the upload dynamic from a webpage.

We convert the image to a base64 code and then save it to the database. MongoDB returns a unique id. We want to integrate this process and make it dynamic. The code we used to connect to mongoDB and upload an image from physical location is available here.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, 
    format = require('util').format,
    fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    //should be triggered by the user upload button
    put();

    //triggered after the upload/button click
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;


        var collection = db.collection('test_insert');

        collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
            //console.dir(results);
            // Let's close the db
            //ret = results[0];

            console.log(results[0]);
            res.end('<img alt="sample" src="data:image/png;base64,' +  results[0].image + '">');
            db.close();
        });
    });


    //res.end("Hello World\n");
}).listen(3030);

function read() {
    var image_base64 = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/2088-1nqsb3l.jpg').toString('base64');

    return image_base64;
    //console.log(base64_data);
}


function put() {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;

        var collection = db.collection('test_insert');
        collection.insert({image: read()}, function(err, docs) {
            console.log("data inserted");
            db.close();
        });
    });
}

function get() {
    var ret;
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
        if(err) throw err;

        var collection = db.collection('test_insert');

        collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
            //console.dir(results);
            // Let's close the db
            ret = results[0];
            db.close();
        });
    });
    return ret;
}

/*
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = db.collection('test_insert');
    collection.insert({a: base64_data}, function(err, docs) {

        collection.count(function(err, count) {
            console.log(format("count = %s", count));
        });

        // Locate all the entries using find
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
            console.dir(results);
            // Let's close the db
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
*/
```

Comment: So, what is your question? Is it how to display the image?

Comment: Can you post your "dynamic" code and tell us, what's your problem with that!?

Comment: the question is - how to post the image directly from the webpage to the database and get back a unique id

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the image via `XMLHttpRequest` from the client to nodejs. Then store it in mongo like you did with the file, you read by `fs.readFileSync`.